# The write interface cannot be used

Tags: cnosdb

cnosdb version:2.3.3.
I used helmchart to deploy a 3+2+2 cnosdb cluster。When I try to write data with command like below：

curl -i -v -u "cnosdb:" -H "Accept: application/json" -XPOST "http://cnosdb-query-svc:8902/api/v1/write?db=public" -d "air,station=XiaoMaiDao visibility=50,temperature=63,pressure=52 1642176000000000000"

```
*   Trying 10.233.35.5:8902...
* Connected to cnosdb-query-svc (10.233.35.5) port 8902 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'cnosdb'
> POST /api/v1/write?db=public HTTP/1.1
> Host: cnosdb-query-svc:8902
> Authorization: Basic Y25vc2RiOg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 83
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< content-length: 0
content-length: 0
< date: Mon, 27 Nov 2023 07:36:32 GMT
date: Mon, 27 Nov 2023 07:36:32 GMT

< 
* Connection #0 to host cnosdb-query-svc left intact
```

Looking at the error message, it seems that the write interface was not found. Why is this?